# The same rows appear twice on my output using jQuery and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

[image: Table with duplicated rows]

- As I wrote in the title, the same rows appear twice.
- In my Firebase firestore (kind of database) there are 3 datas (it means output has to be only 3 rows) but as you can see there are 6 rows without the title(`th`).

So, I want to know why same rows appear twice.

---

**HTML**

```
<table class="artist-list">
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th>이름</th>
   <th>나이</th>
   <th>소속</th>
   <th>성별</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody class="artist-list"></tbody>
</table>
```

**JavaScipt**

```js
const db = firebase.firestore();
db.collection('artistList').get().then(snapshot => {
  snapshot.forEach(doc => {
    var template = `<tr>
      <!-- <th>프로필 사진</th> -->
      <td>${doc.data().name}</td>
      <td>${doc.data().age}세</td>
      <td>${doc.data().group}</td>
      <td>${doc.data().gender}</td>
    </tr>`;
    $('.artist-list').append(template);
  })
})
```

- some words are Korean, but there's no problem with Korean.

**In my database (Firebase Firestore)**

[image: 3 data entries]

there are only 3 datas.

And I don't even know what this serious problem is about.

Comment: Please post code, **data, and results** as text, not screenshots ([how to format code in posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)). [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: You're using `append()`, so the old contents of `.artist-list` are not removed. Try putting `$('.artist-list').empty()` before the loop.

Comment: You've got the class on both the `<table>` and also the `<tbody>`.  jQuery will append to **both of them**.

Comment: If you change it to `$('tbody.artist-list').append(template)` it will only append to the table body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you have cleared tbody of your table?

```
<tbody class="artist-list"></tbody>
```

Before updating the tbody,

```
// below line will delete all table rows
$('.artist-list').empty();
snapshot.forEach(doc => {
  var template = `<tr>
    <!-- <th>프로필 사진</th> -->
    <td>${doc.data().name}</td>
    <td>${doc.data().age}세</td>
    <td>${doc.data().group}</td>
    <td>${doc.data().gender}</td>
  </tr>`;
  $('.artist-list').append(template);
})
```

Comment: This will get rid of the header row also, because the `<table>` is *also* class "artist-list".